# Is there a tool to generate simple CONTRIBUTORS file from a GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, tooling

I know that there are git commands that could extract and summarize contributors information from a repository such as ones from [this link](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4519/list-all-authors-of-a-particular-git-project) but this is not very useful for a GitHub repository since I'd be getting real names and emails.

I'm looking for a CLI tool with these particular features:

- Find contributors of a local (or remote) git repository.
- Associate those contributors with GitHub usernames.
- Produce an ASCII or Markdown summary.

Is there such a tool? I'm asking because I do not think I am the first one to come up with these requirements. It seems like a simple task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Github individual file contributors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430769/getting-github-individual-file-contributors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a tool but check out the GitHub API: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors

It does pretty much everything you're asking for, you just need to parse it and produce output. The information is all there. Sample URL:
https://api.github.com/repos/glowing-bear/glowing-bear/contributors

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing so by interacting with GITHUB API using an external module like pygithub3 as a wrapper for GITHUB and other way around is to clone the repo into a remote directory and then get into the directory and use git shortlog command to get the list using the github log file for that repo:

Check my answer here for reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28228463/3980316