# Get list of contributors who have made commits to a particular file

Tags: javascript, github-api

> I am looking for ways to fetch the author/contributor of a commit. I'm really new to github-api and [this](https://developer.github.com/v3) is giving me more trouble than I imagined.

## We're starting with..

- I have the [list of contributors](https://api.github.com/repos/csitauthority/csitauthority.github.io/contributors)
- I can filter the commits by contributor on the github website with `?author=` like [this](https://github.com/csitauthority/CSITauthority.github.io/commits/master?author=Pratik855)
- It is possible to see contributor in file commits too
  [image: Github displays contributor of a file]

## It should be possible

- All of this makes me think it should be possible to find the contributor to a file by API too.

> ## Problem Description
>
> If I have the URL of the file [such as this](https://github.com/csitauthority/CSITauthority.github.io/blob/master/HUGO/content/post/vlan-101.md), is there a github API that shows me the list of contributors who have made commits to that file?
>
> Or, Do I need to use results of multiple API calls like(for instance)
>
> - [Repository contributors list](https://api.github.com/repos/csitauthority/csitauthority.github.io/contributors)
> - [User Event JSON](https://api.github.com/users/siddhantrimal/events)
>
> `I'm thinking of cross-referencing the outputs of those two^ if everything else fails.`

## Example Output

[This](https://github.com/csitauthority/CSITauthority.github.io/blob/master/HUGO/content/post/vlan-101.md) should return Pratik855

---

## *EDIT

I found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200303/5040900) but this is not quite what I'm looking for. While all the requirements are made, I'm unsure how `https://api.github.com/repos/csitauthority/csitauthority.github.io/commits?=README` translates to `https://api.github.com/repos/csitauthority/csitauthority.github.io/commits?=HUGO/content/page/vlan-101.md` based on `https://github.com/csitauthority/CSITauthority.github.io/blob/master/HUGO/content/post/vlan-101.md` because HUGO can only generate the 3rd kind of canonical URL.

---

## I am using

- Hugo
- Github pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get complete data on all contributors to a particular file in a repository, make a call to the
[*List commits on a repository*](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) endpoint with the file’s repo path as the `path` parameter’s value:

https://api.github.com/repos/csitauthority/CSITauthority.github.io/commits?path=HUGO/content/post/vlan-101.md

That is, the general form is:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits?path=:path-to-file
```

That’ll return a JSON object with an array of all the commits for that file. To get the contributor name from each, you have a choice of using `commit.author.name` or `commit.committer.name` (depending on which of those you actually want) or `author.login` or `committer.login`.

So it’s a single API call — but to get just the names,  process the JSON data you get back.

Here’s a simple example of doing it in JavaScript:

```js
const githubAPI = "https://api.github.com"
const commitsEndpoint = "/repos/csitauthority/CSITauthority.github.io/commits"
const commitsURL = githubAPI + commitsEndpoint
const filepath = "HUGO/content/post/vlan-101.md"
fetch(commitsURL + "?path=" + filepath)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(commits => {
    for (var i = 0; i < commits.length; i++) {
      console.log(commits[i].commit.author.name)
    }
  })
```

And here’s an example of how to skip any duplicate names and end with a set of unique names:

```js
const githubAPI = "https://api.github.com"
const commitsEndpoint = "/repos/csitauthority/CSITauthority.github.io/commits"
const commitsURL = githubAPI + commitsEndpoint
const filepath = "HUGO/content/post/grandfather-problem.md"
fetch(commitsURL + "?path=" + filepath)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(commits => {
    const names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < commits.length; i++) {
      if (!names.includes(commits[i].commit.author.name)) {
        names.push(commits[i].commit.author.name);
      }
    }
    console.log(names.join("\n"));
  })
```

Comment: when I run it against `const filepath = "HUGO/content/post/grandfather-problem.md"` , it returns the same committer twice. How do I filter out unique committers? Thanks!

Comment: See the updated answer for an example of how to skip the duplicates and end up with a set of unique names.

Comment: Wow, that's a really neat solution! Why didn't I think of it? xD I spent all my time looking through documentations to get just the list of committers(not commits) like it shows in gh-dashboard. Many thanks! +1